# A distro with Ubuntu 11.04 and Gnome 3 installed by default

Tags: ubuntu, distribution-choice, gnome3

I remember reading a comment ages ago about a distro that was created with Gnome 3 on top of Ubuntu 11.04. What was that distribution named/where can I find it?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean [gNatty](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1754198)?  It's based on 11.04, but uses Gnome 3; while it's not really stable, it seemed usable to me in a quick run under VirtualBox.

Comment: It's hard not to test a new distro.

Comment: Are you complaining about the upvote? A lot of people wouldn't even bother trying something out for someone else.

Comment: Absolutely not!  I was just saying, new distros are so much fun that it's hard *not* to test it.